# How To Capture WebRTC Stream From Different Page In NodeJS

Tags: node.js, webrtc

I'm new to Node.js and WebRTC concept. I'm trying to make a an audio stream in which one of the page is the music controller and the other page is just playing whatever stream the music controller page is playing.

I based the idea on this link:
https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/capture/video-pc/

But instead of video I just want audio. I'm able to make it work when they are on the same page but there is a problem when capturing stream from different page/url. NodeJS cannot access DOM elements so I'm stuck. I tried accessing the controller page audio element using document.getElementById but its not working. Please help how to get over this.